# Opening a file without making any changes sends out push notifications events

Tags: google-drive-api

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Monitor all changes on the push notifications playground at https://pushnotificationsplayground.appspot.com/
2. Open a file in drive, but do not make any changes

Expected result: there should be no changes that show up
Actual result: You see a push notification for the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It updates `lastViewedByMeDate` attribute, that's why you see a new notification.

Comment: Is there a way to have some attributes of the change sent back similar to how file push notifications work?

This basically makes the common use case a false alarm.

Also, why are there two notifications sent back? Basically if we process both, we might end up doing the same thing twice.